# How to add multiple tray icons in the same application (winapi)?

Tags: c++, winapi, system-tray

It is possible for an application to have more than one tray icon? (kind of like thunderbird does: one for the main application and another when you receive an email and there's an envelope in the notification area)

I tried using ShellNotify_Icon twice in a row but simply return FALSE the second time.
I've also tried using two different NOTIFYICONDATA structures but still nothing. It just adds one.

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation or on google  saying if this is possible or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, is possible add multiple icons.

Comment: How? ShellNotify_Icon twice in a row doesn't work?

Comment: From the documentation on NOTIFYICONDATA: "The Shell uses either (hWnd plus uID) or guidItem to identify which icon to operate on when Shell_NotifyIcon is invoked. You can have multiple icons associated with a single hWnd by assigning each a different uID."

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how you missed that. It always pays to read the documentation. Read it twice just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your application needs to show 2 statuses during runtime, and you wish to display them as 2 different tray icons. Here is the code to update them. I had that use case when I worked on a video-capturing software.

```
BOOL SetTrayIcons(HWND hWnd, int iconType1, int iconType2)
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA iconData1;
    memset(&iconData1, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));

    NOTIFYICONDATA iconData2;
    memset(&iconData2, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));

    // Icon 1
    if (iconType1 == TRAY_DELETE)
    {
        iconData1.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
        iconData1.hWnd = hWnd;
        iconData1.uID = 1; // Change this ID for each icon
        iconData1.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
        iconData1.uFlags = 0;

        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &iconData1);
    }
    else
    {
        HICON hIcon1 = NULL;
        if (iconType1 == TRAY_START)
        {
            hIcon1 = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAINICON), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);
            _tcscpy(iconData1.szTip, SGDVR_STATE_NOT_RECORDING);
        }
        else if (iconType1 == TRAY_REC)
        {
            hIcon1 = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_RECORDING), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);
            _tcscpy(iconData1.szTip, SGDVR_STATE_RECORDING);
        }
        else if (iconType1 == TRAY_NOTREC)
        {
            hIcon1 = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAINICON), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);
            _tcscpy(iconData1.szTip, SGDVR_STATE_NOT_RECORDING);
        }
        _ASSERTE(hIcon1 != 0);

        iconData1.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
        iconData1.hWnd = hWnd;
        iconData1.uID = 1; // Change this ID for each icon
        iconData1.hIcon = hIcon1;
        iconData1.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
        iconData1.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
        iconData1.uCallbackMessage = SG_NOTIFY_MESSAGE;

        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &iconData1);
    }

    // Icon 2 (similar to Icon 1)
    if (iconType2 == TRAY_DELETE)
    {
        iconData2.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
        iconData2.hWnd = hWnd;
        iconData2.uID = 2; // Change this ID for each icon
        iconData2.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
        iconData2.uFlags = 0;

        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &iconData2);
    }
    else
    {
        HICON hIcon2 = NULL;
        if (iconType2 == TRAY_START)
        {
            hIcon2 = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAINICON), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);
            _tcscpy(iconData2.szTip, SGDVR_STATE_NOT_RECORDING);
        }
        else if (iconType2 == TRAY_REC)
        {
            hIcon2 = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_RECORDING), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);
            _tcscpy(iconData2.szTip, SGDVR_STATE_RECORDING);
        }
        else if (iconType2 == TRAY_NOTREC)
        {
            hIcon2 = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAINICON), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);
            _tcscpy(iconData2.szTip, SGDVR_STATE_NOT_RECORDING);
        }
        _ASSERTE(hIcon2 != 0);

        iconData2.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
        iconData2.hWnd = hWnd;
        iconData2.uID = 2; // Change this ID for each icon
        iconData2.hIcon = hIcon2;
        iconData2.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
        iconData2.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
        iconData2.uCallbackMessage = SG_NOTIFY_MESSAGE;

        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &iconData2);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I used it to display a tray icon during recording, and a 'mute' icon when only video is captured.

```
SetTrayIcons(hwnd, TRAY_REC, SGDVRIsMute() ? TRAY_START : TRAY_NOTREC);
```

Then when you just wish to remove the 2 icons, you call:

```
BOOL ClearAllTrayIcons(HWND hWnd)
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA iconData;
    memset(&iconData, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));

    iconData.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    iconData.hWnd = hWnd;
    iconData.uID = 1;
    iconData.uFlags = 0;

    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &iconData);

    iconData.uID = 2;
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &iconData);

    return TRUE;
}
```